# presence/absence for multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset in which the same observation (an object) has several variables that can have the same value (decorative motifs).

```
decor_data <- data.frame(Site= "XYZ", 
                   Motif1 = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C"), 
                   Motif2 = c("C", "D", "D", "A", NA, "B"), 
                   Motif3 = c("B", "A", NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                   Motif4 = c("D", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I now want to create a column for each of the motif values that notes their presence or absence.

I can do this by making a function like this:

```
 presabs.decor <- function(data, motif){
  data <- data %>% dplyr::mutate((!!quo_name (motif)) := case_when((Motif1 == motif | Motif2 == motif | Motif3 == motif | Motif4 == motif) ~ 1, TRUE~0))
}
```

But then I have to give the name of the variable each time, which is obviously a waste of time

```
    decors <- decor_data %>% presabs.decor("A") %>% 
                             presabs.decor("B") %>% 
                             presabs.decor("C") %>% 
                             presabs.decor("D")
```

There are plenty of ways to do this with one column for instance using [dcast](http://chris35wills.github.io/presence_absence_matrix_R/) , but I haven't been able to find anything that works across multiple columns like I need it.

I feel like I am missing something pretty obvious here.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The easiest way would be to `melt` or `tidyr::pivot_longer` your data into long form so it is one column, and then use one of the 1-column solutions you've found using `dcast` or `tidyr::pivot_wider`. You probably need to add a unique row identifier first.

Comment: Thanks! Since the original dataset has many more columns, I was really hoping for a solution that would keep the rows intact. This way I could avoid having to go the route with unique IDs and then rejoining the datasets later. But your way will definitely work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *base*:

```
#get unique motif names
m <- na.omit(unique(unlist(decor_data[, -1])))

cbind(decor_data, 
      sapply(m, function(i) rowSums(decor_data[, -1] == i, na.rm = TRUE)))
#   Site Motif1 Motif2 Motif3 Motif4 A B C D
# 1  XYZ      A      C      B      D 1 1 1 1
# 2  XYZ      B      D      A   <NA> 1 1 0 1
# 3  XYZ      B      D   <NA>   <NA> 0 1 0 1
# 4  XYZ      B      A   <NA>   <NA> 1 1 0 0
# 5  XYZ      A   <NA>   <NA>   <NA> 1 0 0 0
# 6  XYZ      C      B   <NA>   <NA> 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When I tried to run this, I got an error message: `Error in decor_data[, -1] == i : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented`

Comment: @NickG With your example data it works fine, please provide your data as `dput(mydata)`

Comment: @zx8745 I was trying it on my example data, too. I restarted R as well, but to no avail. The error is still there `Error in decor_data[, -1] == i : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning message:
In is.data.frame(x) :
 
 Error in decor_data[, -1] == i : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented`  Very odd. The output you posted is exactly what I was after, though!

Comment: @NickG, I am guessing it is because your data is type `factor`. Starting with R v. 4.0.0 `stringsAsFactors` is now `FALSE` by default. So, for your example data, I can recreate the error if I specify `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`.

Comment: @zx8754 That was it!

Comment: @Andrew Thank you, well spotted. I am using R 4.0.2, no factors in this house anymore :)

Comment: @NickG for future, please share your data as `dput`, so we have the same data.

Answer (score 1):

using `data.table` and `tidyverse`:

```
setDT(decor_data)

motif_vars <- str_subset(names(decor_data), "Motif")

decor_data[, (motif_vars) := map(.SD, as.character), .SD = motif_vars]

motif_values <- decor_data[, motif_vars, with = FALSE] %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  .[!is.na(.)] 

decor_data[, motif := pmap_chr(.SD, ~c(...) %>% .[!is.na(.)] %>% str_c(collapse = "")), .SD = motif_vars]
decor_data[, (motif_values) := map(motif_values, ~str_detect(motif, .x) * 1L)]

decor_data %>% select(-motif)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this does the job perfectly. I prefer zx8754 's base solution since it is significantly shorter, but they both get to the same result.